# Can the use of SimpleImputer be dissociated for different columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working on the Kaggle notebook "Missing Values" from Intermediate Machine Learning course.
I am using the `SimpleImputer` to preprocess a dataframe. 3 columns need to be imputed. I have applied the `SimpleImputer` to each of them together in the same way.
Is there a way to use a different strategy (mean, median ...) for each column separately ?

Here's what I have for the moment:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')
imputed_X_train = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(X_train))
imputed_X_valid = pd.DataFrame(imputer.transform(X_valid))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). This will apply a median imputer to columns in `median_columns_list`, and a mean imputer to columns in `mean_columns_list`:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [("median_imp", SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median'), median_columns_list),
     ("mean_imp", SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean'), mean_columns_list)])
```

Comment: Great tool ! Thank you